# How to deserialize a field in nested array

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am having problem getting hold of one of the field that is in nested array.

First i am trying to iterate through root array of my json like this -

```
                for(SearchHit h : hits){
                    String source = h.getSourceAsString().replace("null","\"\"");
                    
                    TestResponse svcResp = mapper.readValue(source, TestResponse.class);
                    dataResp.add(svcResp);
                }
```

Now the source json would look like this -

```
 {

  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Doe",
      "given": "Jon",
      "middle": "Smith",
      "use": "Commercial"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my pojo would look like this -

```
private String fstNm;
List<Map<String,Object>> name=null;
private List<Map<String,Object>> name;

public String getFstNm() { return fstNm; }


public void setFstNm(List<Map<String, Object>> hits) {

      name = (List) hits.get(0).get("name");

      this.fstNm= (String) name.get(0).get("given");
        

}
```

My Expected Output -

```
{
    "fstNm":"Jon"
}
```

But i am getting actual Output -

```
{
    "fstNm":null,
    "name": [
          {
            "family": "Doe",
            "given": "Jon",
            "middle": "Smith",
            "use": "Commercial"
          }
        ]

   }
```

How do i get my expected output to be working ?

Update Posting my entire pojo -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class TestResponse {

    @JsonProperty("dummyID")
    @JsonAlias("dummyID")
    private String dummyID;

 


    private String fstNm;


    private List<Map<String, Object>> name;

    public String getFstNm() {
        return fstNm;
    }

    public void setFstNm(String fstNm) {
        this.fstNm=fstNm;

    }


    public List<Map<String, Object>> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<Map<String, Object>> name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fstNm= (String) name.get(0).get("given");
    }

    public String getdummyId() {
        return dummyId;
    }

    public void setdummyId(String dummyId) {
        this.dummyId = dummyId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Name your setter `setName` instead `setFstNm` and your json don't  match your code for actual output

Comment: I tried that so now my getter/setter would look like this - public String getName() { return Name; }



    public void setName( List<Map<String, Object>>hits) {

        name = (List) hits.get(0).get("name");

        this.Name = (String) name.get(0).get("given");
    }    but i am getting name=null now

Comment: As your json just use `this.fstNm= (String) hits.get(0).get("given")` in setter and set name if you want

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but worth considering: "given name" and "family name" are often preferable to "first name" and "last name" because depending on the locale or culture, the family name may come before the given name. In other words, a "first" name isn't necessarily always first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set fstName inside the setName method as name property will get parsed.

Not commenting whether you are doing it right or wrong. Just posting a simple solution that will work and of course there are many other ways of achieving it like custom deserializer etc.

```
public class Test {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String input = "{\r\n" + "\r\n" + "  \"name\": [\r\n" + "    {\r\n" + "      \"family\": \"Doe\",\r\n"
                + "      \"given\": \"Jon\",\r\n" + "      \"middle\": \"Smith\",\r\n"
                + "      \"use\": \"Commercial\"\r\n" + "    }\r\n" + "  ]\r\n" + "}";
        System.out.println(input);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(input, TestResponse.class));
    }
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "fstNm" })
    protected static class TestResponse {

        private String fstNm;
        
        
        private List<Map<String, Object>> name;

        public String getFstNm() {
            return fstNm;
        }

        public void setFstNm(String fstNm) {
            this.fstNm=fstNm;

        }       
        

        public List<Map<String, Object>> getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(List<Map<String, Object>> name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.fstNm= (String) name.get(0).get("given");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pojo [fstNm=" + fstNm + ", name=" + name + "]";
        }
        
        

    }
}
```

Output:

```
{

  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Doe",
      "given": "Jon",
      "middle": "Smith",
      "use": "Commercial"
    }
  ]
}
Pojo [fstNm=Jon, name=[{family=Doe, given=Jon, middle=Smith, use=Commercial}]]
```

Comment: I tried what you have posted but i am getting  this - {"fstNm": null,
      "name": [
        {
          "family": "Doe",
          "given": "Jon",
          "middle": "Smith",
          "use": "Commercial"
        }
      ]}

Comment: you can just copy paste the test class and run it it should work. or else post your entire class file

Comment: i have posted my entire pojo in the post

Comment: Just try removing lombok annotations and add  @JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "fstNm" })

Comment: You could add NoArgsConstructor as well may be due to AllArgsConstructor it is initialized using the constructor rather than the setters.

Comment: Awesome this worked for me. I removed lombok annotations and added @JsonPropertyOrder and it worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: why don't you use `Map<String, Object> source = h.getSourceAsMap();` instead of parsing the JSON with the Mapper?